# Make Sessions work with WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Normally this works:

page 1

```
  <? session_start();

   $_SESSION['note']  = "hello";

 ?>
```

page 2

```
<? session_start();

   echo $_SESSION['note'];

?>
```

Navigate to Page 1 to start the session and load the variable. Navigate to page 2 and the variable is alive. Easy.

Now I come to WordPress.

WordPress has a 'theme' in a particular folder, with its own header and footer. The 'template', so to speak.

To create a page, you login to the admin section, click add page and you are greeted with a blank screen. If you type nothing, and 'publish' all you will see is the header and footer.

That means, any php coding that is page specific is entered onto the blank text box, which when displayed is sandwiched in between the default 'theme' header and footer.

So, it is in this section I enter page 1 (same as above):

```
<? session_start();

   $_SESSION['note']  = "hello";

?>
```

then page 2 (same as above):

```
<? session_start();

   echo $_SESSION['note'];

?>
```

Result? Nothing.

---

So this is what I tried:

Installing a wp plugin called WP sessions manager.

After installing the plugin, and trying the code as above, which did not work, I tried this syntax p1:

```
<? $wp_session = WP_Session::get_instance();

   $wp_session['note'] = "hello";

 ?>
```

and this p2

```
<? $wp_session = WP_Session::get_instance();
   $wp_session['note'] = "hello";
?>
```

Result? Still nothing.

I tried placing the same code at the top of the index and header pages for the theme, in the theme folder and the primary folder, but nothing works.

Since the session works fine with standalone php pages, something to do with wordpress is blocking the session, keeping it from working, and I am trying to figure out why and fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Now, the first thing that your theme should do is `session_start()`. Put it just on the top of header.php or on the top of index.php. And right after that use:

```
die(var_dump($_SESSION));
```

If that doesn't work, you might have a problem with your theme.

Check your theme to see if sessions get destroyed somewhere. Search for `session_destroy()`.

Comment: where does the ini_set code go? and I checked every file and nothing has a session_destroy() in it ...

Comment: @user6096423 put it after `session_start()` in index.php or header.php. What does the var_dump return?

Comment: I've got at the top of the index page: <? session_start();
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
die(var_dump($_SESSION)); .... how do I read var_dump? I dont see anything  ...

Comment: Are you sure that you activated the right theme? You must definitely see the result of var_dump. If not, your file (index.php or header.php) is not getting loaded.

Comment: OK, I moved the code to the header. now I see "array(1) { ["note"]=> string(5) "hello" } "; so it's picking up that session variable, but the issue is how can I display it on another page?

Comment: If you use `die()`, the rest of your page shouldn't be loaded. Basically your website should be white and the only thing that you see is what var_dump returns and no, there is no echo needed. Try to delete something (don't forget the backup) to see if the files really get loaded.

Comment: exactly, i see a white page only, and all I see at the top is >> array(1) { ["note"]=> string(5) "hello" } << ... the session variable picks up in the stand alone php pages, and I can echo the session var and see it displayed at the top of the page because it is in the header. But when I try to place it in the body of the web page I don's see it ("body" means the textarea WP give you to add code to show your web page). I am trying to find out how to 'read' that session variable in the body of the page. Tried <? echo $_SESSION['note']; >? but nothing shows up.

Comment: Try to put `session_start()` also on the top of your body page (same place where you try to read the session). If you can't read it, try it with `var_dump($_SESSION['note'])` to see what it returns.

Comment: I have a problem more basic than that I just discovered ... WP doesn't render PHP code in it's text editor thing. I have to solve that problem first.

Comment: The text area inside WP was deleting the php. The workaround was to use page templates. Now the session variables show inside the page.